# Can one of the sheva berachot be said outside a wedding context?

Tags: halacha, wedding, sheva-brachos

Are there any sources which speak to the possibility of saying one of the sheva berachot outside of the wedding ceremony and ensuing celebratory period? (Excluding borei pri hagafen). I'm most interested if there are cases/examples where "shehakol bara lichvodo" may be said outside of the entire wedding context.

Comment: Why might you expect there to be such sources? Few blessings have multiple applications. Usually each situation has its own dedicated liturgy.

Comment: asher Yatsar...